# Logstash 7.9.3 not starting

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

[only this content shows up, while kibana and elastic search both are running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Jki.png)

[logstash.conf looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaOAb.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: this issue related to heap size,Check you environment variables ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g".  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/advanced-configuration.html

Comment: but that is just a warning right?

Comment: it's maybe like an error ,set variable

Comment: it resolved, but the issue was resolved by replacing JAVA_OPTS with LS_JAVA_OPTS in the environment variable.